# Sort and Order columns Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, sorting

I have a code to create a CSV with  information from another CSV file. In my new CSV file, I would like to save only 20 rows sorted from highest to lowest of `row ['impressions']`

I read something about pandas but I don't find anything about how to do it!

To be more clear, I shared some images:

before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kx5M.png)

after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV115.png)

Code:

```
import csv
input_file = 'report_2017_12_11_12_31_19UTC.csv'
output_file= "All_Data_Tags.csv"

with open(input_file) as csvfile, open(output_file,  "w") as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    cols = ("domain","ddomain","opportunities", "impressions", "fillRate", "DATA")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=cols, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        row['fillRate'] = '{:.2f}'.format(float(row['fillRate']) * 100)
        if row['ddomain']  == "":
            if row['domain']  == "":
                row['ddomain'] = "App"
                row['domain'] = " "
        if row['domain'] == row['ddomain']:
            row['domain'] = "Real Site"    
        if row['domain']  == "":
            row['domain'] = "Detected Only"
        if row['ddomain']  == "":
            row['ddomain'] = "Vast Media"
        if row['ddomain'] != row['domain']:
            if row['ddomain'] != "Vast Media":
                if row['domain'] != "Real Site":
                    if row['domain'] != "Detected Only":
                        if row['ddomain'] != "App":
                            row['DATA'] = "FAKE"
                        else:
                            row['DATA'] = "OK"
                    else:
                        row['DATA'] = "OK"
                else:
                    row['DATA'] = "OK"
            else:
                row['DATA'] = "OK"

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You don't have any code showing an attempt to look at `row['impressions']`.

Comment: please, check cols... @pstatix

Comment: Yes you have defined it in `cols`, but in your `for row in reader` you never try to access `row['impressions']`. How do you expect to sort on something if you never look at it?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it, I'm asking here if someone can help me with that

Comment: You can't sort a stream - you need to store your rows in memory (in a `list`), sort this list (cf the builtin `sorted()`, slice it to get the 20 first rows and only then write them back to file. Note that this may be a problem if you have huge input files, in this case you'll want some database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer:

code:

```
import pandas as pd 


movies = pd.read_csv('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv')

movies = movies.sort_values(['impressions'], ascending=False)

movies = movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")

movies = pd.read_csv('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv', nrows=21)

movies = movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")
```

Comment: Just delete your post

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataFrame.sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) function of the pandas framework, passing the column name(s),you wish to sort, to the `by` argument and setting `axis` to 1.

You can find similar examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: Can I get an explanation please as to why my post was downvoted?

Comment: "Can I get an explanation please as to why my post was downvoted?" => possibly because your answer is based on a tool that's not used by the OP and actually not necessary ? (nb : I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: Do you mean pandas? The OP is actually the one suggesting that sorting/ordering can be done with pandas but couldn't find any info on how to do it...

Comment: Indeed - but once again I am _not_ (I repeat : "not") the downvoter, so this was a wild guess at best.